# svn info for a specific revision: exception when file does not exist

Tags: svn

As part of an upload script, I launch this command :

```
svn info https://svnserver/svn/repos/path/to/file.png -r 811 --xml
```

A problem appears when the specified file does not exist anymore in the repository. I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
svn: E160013: '/svn/repos/!svn/rvr/943/path/to/file.png' path not found
```

As you can see in the response, it searches the file in revision 943, although I specified the revision 811 in my request (and in the revision 943, the files does not exist anymore).

Why does it happens, and how do I circumvent that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are never deleted in Subversion. I suspect the problem is that the file no longer exists in the URL provided, and thus couldn't return revision 811 of that file from that location. What you can do is *pin* the URL to a specific revision of the repository:

```
svn info -r 811 --xml https://svnserver/svn/repos/path/to/file.png@811
```

Note the `@811`. This will retrieve revision 811 of the file which was located in revision 811 of the URL `http://svnserver/svn/repos/path/to/file.png`

Normally, when you request a particular revision of a file, you should specify the revision in both the `-r` parameter and in the *pin* by using `@` appended to the end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I knew very well that the file was not "deleted" but I didn't know about the "@" syntax.